# Laravel Backpack DevTools: Create update migrations?

Tags: laravel-backpack

after diving into Laravel and Backpack just two days ago I already built a working prototype for an internal CRUD tool.

I used the DevTools to create my entity models and migrations and that worked fine. But I am still looking for a way to manage my field update / alter table migrations? Right now I still manually create my update migration file with a Schema::table() command.

Isn't that something the DevTools are supposed to handle through the web UI?

Maybe I'm just blind...

Thanks & kind regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

DevTools does not offer “update migration” or “alter table” functionality at the moment. It will be very difficult to create one - the migration itself is easy enough to create, but the rest of the code (Model, CRUD, etc) would be very difficult to do, since the dev might have edited the generated files.

We do plan to add an “edit” functionality for migrations in the near future. But it will be limited in scope. It will cover the use case where you forgot to add a certain db column… which I assume is what most of us need, most of the time.

But until then, the only way to do that is manually… like they did “in the old days”, sorry.